# What is the probability of a decimal digit in irrational number to repeat itself?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, irrational-numbers

I have this question, by my intuition the probability would be 0, since we do not know what the next irrational number decimal digit will be in base 10.

Does anybody have a more concrete idea, or is there already a solution to this ?

EDIT: Why I think it is not $1/10$ is because we could change the base from base 10 to let's say base 100 and then the probability would be $1/100$. That is also why I think it is zero.

EDIT 2 : What I wanted to ask was, that if we take the decimal digits of an irrational number. Let's say we take those digits in base 10. We do not know what will the next decimal digit be, as they go to infinity. But we could say, that the next digit can be any digit from 0 to 9. But we can change the base of these digits to base 2, where the next digit would have 1/2 probability to be 0 or 1. But that is a contradiction since 1/2 is not the same as 1/10 or if we pick a base 100, it is not the same as 1/100

EDIT 3: So we also have the probability $1/100$ to reconstruct the digits in base 100 back to base 10, since the numbers are always generating at random order since the number is irrational.

Comment: And if we change the base to 2, then every irrational number is $1.0101010...$?

Comment: This is not clear. How are you choosing the irrational?

Comment: @eyeballfrog no, let's say that the irrational number of $sqrt(2) $ approximately 1.011010100000100111100110011001... , in binary form 

We also cannot see the pattern.

Comment: I will formulate my question a little differently, that we cannot, know if the base 10 decimal digit will repeat itself, and we can see that if we change the base, and then try to change it back again

Comment: This is very hard to follow.  Obviously the probability depends on the base involved...why would you think otherwise?

Comment: This question very unclear.  You talk about changing bases... are you trying to talk about some property of numbers which is constant regardless what base it is you are representing things in?  What property precisely is that then?  It is much clearer if you pick a single base and stick with it.  Next, with what distribution are you choosing the irrational number itself?  With what distribution are you choosing "the digit"?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking, but perhaps this will help:  One way to choose a random real number between $0$ and $1$ is to choose a sequence of digits one at a time, uniformly at random.  with probability $1$ the number you produce is irrational and, clearly, the probability that the $n^{th}$ choice matches the $(n+1)^{st}$ is $\frac 1b$ if you are in base $b$.

Comment: Now... it is worth pointing out that [Almost every](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) irrational number has infinitely many $1$'s in its base 10 representation.  Similarly, almost every irrational number has infinitely many $2$'s, etc... I would have expected, once you have better explained your question, that the true probability you are after is $1$... not $0$.  Similarly, almost every irrational number has two back to back $1$'s in its base 10 representation somewhere, and so on...  This seen because the probability of it not happening is zero.

Comment: It depends on the irrational number chosen as well. If you choose [Liouville's Constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillesConstant.html) or its multiples, the probability is also $1$. We also "know all of its digits".

Comment: What I wanted to ask was, that if we take the decimal digits of an irrational number. Let's say we take those digits in base 10. We do not know what will the next decimal digit be, as they go to infinity. But we could say, that the next digit can be any digit from 0 to 9. But we can change the base of these digits to base 2, where the next digit would have $1/2$ probability to be 0 or 1. But that is a contradiction since $1/2$ is not the same as $1/10$ or if we pick a base 100, it is not the same as $1/100$

Comment: That makes no sense.  So what if the probability changes between bases?  Look at it this way;  if you really believed the probability of repetition in base $2$ was $0$ then you'd believe that, with probability $1$, every binary irrational was either $.1010...$ or $.01010...$ with probability $1$.

Comment: @lulu For base 2 we can certainly say with probability 1 that then next digit will be $0$ or $1$, so we have two options which implies that the probability of the digit $1$ to show is $1/2$.

Comment: @lulu If we would pick base 1000....0 then the probability would be 1/10000...0 , and now we would want to reconstruct the base 10 out of that base, to be able to do that, we wouldn't know what the next number in that base would be since they go to infinity, thus we cannot reconstruct back to base 10.

Comment: I have to note that I am an undergaduate and there might be a theorem that I do not know of

Comment: Not following.  You said you believe that, in base $2$ in particular, the probability of repeating a digit is $0$.  Thus, suppose the first digit is $1$, so your irrational starts $.1\cdots$.  Now you think the next digit is $0$ with probability $1$, right?  Because the probability of repetition is $0$.  So it must be $.10\cdots$.  And then the third digit must be $1$, and so on.

Comment: @lulu Okay I do believe that in base 2 the probability of the next digit to repeat itself is $1/2$, because it can be either the "zero digit" or the "one digit". But we wouldn't be able to reconstruct from base 2 to base 10, because there are always 0 and 1 generating at random order and we wouldn't know which 0 and 1 to pick to get back into base 10. At at very long length of digits of course

Comment: This is nonsense.  Obviously, there is no difficulty converting a number written in one base into another base.  That has nothing whatsoever to do with the probability of repetition.  I don't think you have a coherent question in mind.

Comment: @lulu I  will construct an example of what I had in mind: we have square root of two which is 1.41421356237 approximately and going on. So the digit 4 is 0110 and the digit 1 is just 1 in binary, here we could think that the square root of two is : $1.01101_{(2)} =  1.41_{(10)}$ But we could choose $01$ and $101$ as a number itself and say that square root of two is equal to $1.01101_{(2)} = 1.15_{(10)}$

Comment: @lulu And at very big numbers, when we do not have an idea what base 10 number the next digit will be, we also cannot know what the next base 2 digit will be

Comment: Really, you aren't making any sense.  We only need finitely many digits of a base $10$ decimal to determine some fixed portion of the base $2$ equivalent.  Obviously if we have no idea what base $10$ number we are dealing with we can't say anything.  But enough.  I don't think my comments are helping in any way, so I will stop.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First... you seem to be confusing the concept of an [irrational number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number) with the concept of a [normal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number).

It is not true that given a specific irrational number that the digits are equally distributed.  Consider [Liouville's Constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillesConstant.html) written in base 10, $0.11010010001000010000010000001\dots$  This number has no $2$'s, $3$'s, $4$'s, etc... appearing in its decimal expansion anywhere.

Now, you are probably talking about choosing an irrational number at random (*which you never clearly specified*).  We can in this case refer to the $n$'th digit in base $b$ of such an irrational number and it will be a particular digit with probability $\frac{1}{b}$ and the $n+1$'st digit will be independent of the first and also be that digit also with probability $\frac{1}{b}$.

Let us define random variables.  Let $X$ be our randomly selected irrational number.  Let $X_n^{(b)}$ be the $n$'th digit right of the decimal of $X$ as represented in base $b$.

We do have that $\Pr\left(X_n^{(b)}=X_{n+1}^{(b)}\right)=\frac{1}{b}$ for every $b$.

Your complaint that $\Pr\left(X_n^{(p)}=X_{n+1}^{(p)}\right)=\frac{1}{p}\neq \frac{1}{b}$ is completely irrelevant.  $X_n^{(p)}$ is not the same as $X_n^{(b)}$...  There is no contradiction here.  There is no reason to expect $\Pr\left(X_n^{(b)}=X_{n+1}^{(b)}\right)$ to equal $\Pr\left(X_n^{(p)}=X_{n+1}^{(p)}\right)$.  When you change from one base to another... *things change*.  Yes, some of the fundamental properties of the number remain the same, however the frequency of the digits does not need to stay the same at all...